# numpy genfromtxt breaks on #

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv file that includes some `#`:

```
a,1,asdf
a#,2,asdf
```

When I try to use numpy genfromtxt, it fails:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('TestCSV.csv', delimiter=',')

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #2 (got 1 columns instead of 3)
```

As far as I can tell, the `#` is the problem. What is going on here? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide the full command that you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` is a special character for comments. To load your data with the `genfromtxt`, you have to replace it.

```
numpy.genfromtxt('txt', delimiter=',', dtype=str, comments='%')
```

And the output is:

```
array([['a', '1', 'asdf'],
       ['a#', '2', 'asdf']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Note that I replaced it by `%`.

Also, since your data has several types, I had to define `dtype`.